# Putting hyperlinks in an arraylist

Tags: java, android

Let's say you are doing a book report. In the sources cited you'll either do two things:

A)  Google: www.google.com

or

B) Google

^B having the link embedded and underlined so the user knows to click the link.

Can I do this with a simple array-list in my `strings.xml`?
I have a list of strings that I want to use. I was starting out with something like this.

```
<string-array name="links">
    <item>www.stackoverflow.com</item>
    <item>www.google.com</item>
    <item>www.distrowatch.org</item>
</string-array>
```

I was thinking I can link the list into a `listview` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse you are,

Just `getStringArray()` from Resources,

Like,

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] webLinksArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.links);
```

Now, use this `webLinksArray` in your `ListView` adapter.

**Or using code, you can directly create ArrayAdapter from Resource ID**

```
// Create ArrayAdapter from string array resource id
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.links, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
// Apply the adapter to the ListView
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Is this what you want or I misunderstood ?